# RSpec Capybara not finding element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xpath, rspec, capybara

I'm writing a feature test in Rails using RSpec an Capybara. For some reason it doesn't an element by it's id. I've tried several thing to see why it's not finding the element but nothing helped.

Here is my test

```
require 'rails_helper'

include Warden::Test::Helpers

feature 'Dipole options checkbox' do
  before(:each) do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    @group = FactoryGirl.create(:group)
    @user.groups << @group
    @stack = FactoryGirl.create(:stack, user: @user, group: @group)
    @param_set = FactoryGirl.create(:param_set, user: @user, group: @group, stack: @stack)
  end

  scenario "when check #dipole-options should be visible" do
    login_as(@user, scope: :user)
    visit "/param_sets/#{@param_set.id}/edit#box"

    page.find(:path, "//input[@id='param_set_mat_dipoles']")

   end
end
```

I have done some debugging and when I look at the HTML that is returned I can see the id param_set_mat_dipoles is present

```
(byebug) body.include? "#param_set_mat_dipoles"
true
```

But when I check with in the rspec console

```
page.find("#param_set_mat_dipoles")
```

it cannot find the element.

I've done some research and it is able to find the ID of the parent div but when I check the total number op elements (paragraph/p) in that ID it's not finding the last 2.

Has anybody have this before? Could it be that the element is to deeply nested to Capybara cannot in find it?

PS: This is the xpath that it can reach:

```
path="/html/body/div/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/div[4]/p[7]"
```

It would find the xpath that I need:

```
path="/html/body/div/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/div[4]/p[9]"
```

Comment: This is a guess, but try using `page.find("#param_set_mat_dipoles", visible: false)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue. It turned out that on my view page if the user wasn't part of a certain group that it would show the field that I was looking for.

The actual code was OK.